Why assigning values in vector inside a for loop is slower than doing with a range inside the vector?
Let's create a vector (of length 50000):
vec <- rep(x = "a", times = 50000)

Now we want to assign all the elements between the indexes 41000 and 48000 to a new value ("b")
First method,
vec[41000:48000] <- "b"

On my machine, it takes arround 0.106 seconds
Second method, (for loop)
for (i in 41000:48000){ vec[i] <- "b" }

On my machine, it takes arround 0.125 seconds.
What could explain the difference ?
Thanks !

R is a vectorized language and under the hood it has been optimized such that the range operation is fast and performant.  If you check the source code for R (which I believe is C), you would see this.

Could you please do proper benchmarking, e.g. using the microbenchmark package? Also, have you recreated the original vector before timing the second approach? Maybe try switching off the JIT compiler too.

I cannot reproduce this behavior. The vectorized assignment is 50x faster.

@TimBiegeleisen but you wouldn't expect the observed timings based on that knowledge.

Yes, sorry i just re run the code and it appears that the vectorized assigment is faster.

No, vectorization is faster
vec <- rep(x = "a", times = 50000)

f1 <- function() {
    vec[41000:48000] <- "b"
    vec
}

f2 <- function() {
    for (i in 41000:48000) {
        vec[i] <- "b"
    }
    vec
}

microbenchmark(
    f1(),
    f2(),
    check = "equal",
    unit = "relative"
)

which shows
Unit: relative
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 f1() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
 f2() 9.458217 5.225293 6.660215 6.661513 5.950026 4.613076   100


Yes, next time i will use the microbenchmark package to properly read the results. Just updated my post. Thanks.

I think this can be difficult for people used to compiled languages to understand because in, for example, C, the compiler would optimise this to (something like) one memset() call whereas in R the for loop actually calls the [<- function 7001 times.

@SamR yes, that's true and a good point

Actually I think that top level loops are JIT compiled by default these days so it's probably not quite as simple as that - you'd have to look at disassembled loop to see exactly what it does. But ultimately the effect is the same, as you've demonstrated.
